# Show that a certain group is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $$N:=\langle\{g^2:g\in G\}\rangle$$ Prove that $N$ is a normal subgroup.

I am quite not sure how to start on this exercise. I heard that this can be proven by using the notion of an index of a group but since we did not cover this in the lecture I think it should not be used. Has someone a hint for a more basic solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x g^2 x^{-1} = (x g x^{-1}) (x g x^{-1}) = (x g x^{-1})^{2} \in N$.